# operadores &, * en c++ y su uso en clases

Tags: c++

En el metodo dentro de la clase objeto... cual es la diferencia entre

```
int getEdad(){
    return edad;
}

int& getEdad(){
    return edad;
}


int* getEdad(){
    return &edad;
}
```

¿Algun curso o explicacion mas detallado de punteros pero referido a clases en c++ ?

Answer (score 5):

```
int getEdad(){ return edad; }
```

Esta versión devuelve una copia de `edad`. Dicha copia será totalmente independiente de la variable original y tendrá su propio ciclo de vida.

```
int& getEdad(){ return edad; }

int* getEdad(){ return &edad; }
```

En estas dos versiones devuelves una referencia de `edad` (en forma de referencia y de puntero). La principal diferencia con la primera versión es que desde fuera de la versión podrías llegar a modificar la variable miembro `edad`.

Ahora bien. ¿que implicaciones tiene usar un método u otro? Responder a esta pregunta no es algo trivial. Cada opción tiene sus ventajas y sus inconvenientes:

**Por valor**

La principal ventaja de esta solución es que mantiene el encapsulamiento intacto. Será imposible modificar la variable miembro `edad` a partir del valor de retorno, lo que impide, por ejemplo, valores incorrectos:

```
int a = getEdad();
a = -1; // edad no cambia de valor
```

La principal desventaja la encontramos al devolver objetos complejos. Devolver una copia de un objeto implica copiar todo su estado (incluido el estado de los objetos anidados), lo cual consume tiempo de ejecución.

**Por referencia**

Al devolver el valor por referencia ofrecemos la posibilidad de evitar realizar copias innecesarias, lo cual puede mejorar los tiempos de ejecución (eso y que hay objetos que pueden tener deshabilitado el constructor copia).

El peaje a pagar es que estamos exponiendo la variable miembro y eso puede permitir que se le asignen valores no válidos:

```
int& a = getEdad();
a = -1; // edad valdrá -1
```

Eso sí, que la función nos devuelva una referencia no implica que tengamos que aprovechar dicha característica. Así podemos hacer una copia sin problemas:

```
int a = getEdad(); // creamos una copia
int& b = getEdad(); // creamos una referencia
```

Su principal uso suele encontrarse al devolver objetos miembro complejos, ya que permitimos modificar sus propiedades sin tener que duplicar su interfaz:

```
escena.getConfiguracion().setColorBase(0x224466);
```

**por puntero**

Esta solución es muy similar a la anterior.

Yo destacaría dos diferencias significativas:

- Crear una copia del objeto implica un código ligeramente mas feo:

  ```
  int a = *getEdad();
  ```
- los punteros pueden crear confusión sobre si el que obtiene el puntero ha de realizar el correspondiente delete:

  ```
  int* a = *getEdad();
  delete a; // es lo correcto?
  ```

Su principal uso debería ser devolver objetos que el receptor debería eliminar, para evitar crear confusión.

Como nota final comentar que la segunda vía no se suele encontrar en código antiguo, siendo las más comunes la primera y la tercera.

Comment: perfecto gracias !

Answer (score 2):

El ampersand está jugando el papel de referencia. Si conoces el papel de un puntero, la referencia es un concepto similar.

Puede que esto te suene de los punteros, donde puedes devolver la dirección de memoria de una variable y luego al desreferenciarla modificar el valor de la variable original. Por ejemplo, tercera función (`int* getEdad()`, la que devuelve un puntero):

```
// Pongamos que inicialmente la edad es 18.
int* fuera = getEdad();
*fuera = 20;

// Esto imprimirá 20.
std::cout << *(getEdad()) << std::endl;
```

Con las referencias puedes hacer lo mismo. Pongamos el ejemplo pero ahora con la segunda función (`int& getEdad()`):

```
// De nuevo la edad inicial es 18.
int& fuera = getEdad();
fuera = 20;

// Esto también imprime 20.
std::cout << getEdad() << std::endl;
```

Si ya existen los punteros, ¿para qué queremos las referencias si parece que hacen lo mismo? Porque las referencias se diferencian de los punteros en dos cosas:

1. Un puntero lo tienes que desreferenciar de forma explícita si quieres modificar su contenido, como hacemos en el primer bloque de código con los asteriscos en la asignación y luego al hacer el `cout`. Con una referencia de C++, es implícito esto.
2. Como las referencias no son punteros, no pueden alojar el valor NULL, por lo que se entiende que siempre tendrán un valor seguro, evitando hacer comprobaciones tipo `variable == NULL`.

Comment: perfecto gracias !

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Algun curso o explicacion mas detallado de punteros pero referido a clases en c++ ?

No hay diferencias en los usos de punteros con [datos básicos](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) o con objetos. En ambos casos los punteros funcionan de la misma manera: contienen una dirección de memoria la cuál puede ser (o no ser) la dirección de memoria de un dato.

#### Nociones básicas.

Las funciones que has puesto, siempre y cuando pertenezcan a un objeto<sup>1</sup> devolverían respectivamente:

1. `int getEdad() { return edad; }` copia de `edad`.
2. `int& getEdad() { return edad; }` referencia a `edad`.
3. `int* getEdad() { return &edad; }` puntero a `edad`.

Estos tres estilos de devolver datos desde una función tienen diferencias elementales.

- En el primer caso obtienes una **copia del dato interno** y cualquier modificación sobre la misma no afectará al dato original; por otro lado, esta copia podrá tener un ciclo de vida diferente al dato original.
- En el segundo caso obtienes una **referencia al dato interno**, esto te permite hacer modificaciones sobre la referencia que serán reflejadas en el dato original; pero si el dato original es eliminado tendrás una [referencia colgante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referencia_colgante) y operar sobre esta referencia causará comportamientos inesperados en tu programa... por este motivo (entre otros) se considera una mala práctica devolver una referencia a un dato interno.
- En el tercer caso obtienes un **puntero al dato interno**, a través del puntero podrías modificar el dato original así que tiene las mismas desventajas que la referencia.

A grandes rasgos, la diferencia entre puntero y referencia a un dato interno es que una vez creada la referencia no puede apuntar a otro dato mientras que el puntero si. Por otro lado un puntero puede ser nulo mientra que una referencia no.

#### Nociones intermedias.

Que devuelvas una referencia no implica que vayas a tener una referencia. En otras palabras: el tipo de retorno de una función no tiene por que ser el tipo usado para almacenar el retorno; supón que tenemos esta clase:

```
struct S
{
    int edad{};

    int  copia()      { return edad;  }
    int& referencia() { return edad;  }
    int* puntero()    { return &edad; }
};
```

Podemos guardar una referencia a el dato devuelto en todos los casos:

```
S s;
const int& referencia1 = s.copia();
int& referencia2 = s.referencia();
int& referencia3 = *s.puntero();
```

Tanto `referencia2` como `referencia3` serían una referencia a `s.edad` y cualquier operación sobre una de esas referencias se reflejaría tanto en la otra como en el dato original.

En cuanto a `referencia1` sería una referencia a un dato temporal (`S::copia` devuelve un dato por copia) y C++ no permite este tipo de referencias a no ser que sean constantes. Una referencia constante a un dato temporal alarga el ciclo de vida del dato hasta el final del ciclo de vida de la referencia, en caso contrario tendríamos una referencia colgante.

De la misma manera podemos guardar un puntero a el dato devuelto:

```
S s;
int* puntero1 = &s.copia();
int* puntero2 = &s.referencia();
int* puntero3 = s.puntero();
```

Tanto `puntero2` como `puntero3` contendrían la dirección de memoria de `s.edad` y se podría modificar `s.edad` a traves de dichos punteros.

El caso de `puntero1` es un error de compilación: no se permite obtener la dirección de memoria de un valor temporal

Por último podemos el dato por copia independientemente de lo que devuelva la función:

```
S s;
int dato1 = s.copia();
int dato2 = s.referencia();
int dato3 = *s.puntero();
```

En los tres casos, incluido el de `dato2`, tendremos una copia de `s.edad`.

#### Nociones avanzadas.

El [et](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%26) (`&`) puede usarse en otro contexto en la declaración de una función miembro:

```
struct S
{
    int edad{};

    int  copia() &&      { std::cout << "c&&\n"; return edad;  }
    int& referencia() && { std::cout << "r&&\n"; return edad;  }
    int* puntero() &&    { std::cout << "p&&\n"; return &edad; }

    int  copia() &      { std::cout << "c&\n"; return edad;  }
    int& referencia() & { std::cout << "r&\n"; return edad;  }
    int* puntero() &    { std::cout << "p&\n"; return &edad; }
};
```

La versión con un et (`&`) corresponde a las llamadas de la función miembro cuando el objeto propietaro no es un objeto temporal. La versión con dos et (`&&`) es para cuando la función miembro es llamada desde un objeto temporal:

```
S s{};

auto a = s.copia();      // muestra c&
auto b = s.referencia(); // muestra r&
auto c = s.puntero();    // muestra p&

auto d = S{}.copia();      // muestra c&&
auto e = S{}.referencia(); // muestra r&&
auto f = S{}.puntero();    // muestra p&&
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que en el ejemplo anterior `e` es una referencia colgante y `f` es un puntero a datos que ya no existen, porque obtuvieron referencias o punteros a datos temporales.

---

<sup>1</sup>Y tuviera cada una un nombre distinto, ya que no se puede sobrecargar por retorno... bueno sí que se puede (con un poco de brujería) pero no es lo que toca hablar en esta pregunta :)

Comment: Una duda sobre capítulo de avanzado . ¿Qué ventaja añade las funciones con &&, si se aplica sobre objetos temporales que realmente son objetos que están simplemente inicializados sus variables miembro? ¿Si hago std::move(s) se llamaría a la función &&?.